# Removing columns from a data frame with repeated values

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have the following data frame containing characters and numbers, and NA:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c("notfound","NOT FOUND","NOT FOUND"), b=c(NA,"NOT FOUND","NOT FOUND"), c=c("not found",2,3), d=c("not   found","NOT FOUND","NOT FOUND"), e=c("234","NOT FOUND",NA))
```

> ```
>           a         b         c           d         e
> 1  notfound      <NA> not found not   found       234
> 2 NOT FOUND NOT FOUND         2   NOT FOUND NOT FOUND
> 3 NOT FOUND NOT FOUND         3   NOT FOUND      <NA>
> ```

I would like to remove all the columns where all the entries are "not found", "NOT found", "NOT FOUND" "notfound". basically if `tolower(gsub(" ","",df)=="notfound")`. It seems like this operation does not work on data frames. Are there any alternatives?

The desired output would be:

> ```
>          d            e
> 1    not found          234
> 2            2    NOT FOUND
> 3            3         <NA>
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grepl` with a regular expression to search for strings matching that expression and keep only those columns where some elements don't show a match (indicated by `FALSE` `grepl` output) so that the number of matches for that column is less than `nrow(df)`. This pattern matches strings that start with "not" and end with "found", and `grepl` is set to be case-insensitive.

```
is_nf <- 
  sapply(df, grepl, pattern = '(?=^not).*found$', 
         perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)


df[colSums(is_nf) < nrow(df)]
#           b         c         e
# 1      <NA> not found       234
# 2 NOT FOUND         2 NOT FOUND
# 3 NOT FOUND         3      <NA>
```

I'm guessing you'd also want to remove columns where the only non "not found" is NA.

```
is_na <- is.na(df)

df[colSums(is_nf | is_na) < nrow(df)]
#           c         e
# 1 not found       234
# 2         2 NOT FOUND
# 3         3      <NA>
```